# How to apply sorting when adding a row as a DOM node

Tags: datatables

I have a use case where I need to add rows dynamically via javascript. I want to add the row as a DOM node inline as it is what best suits my circumstances. So I am doing something like the following:

```
var name  // String
var dob    // Date
table.row.add($('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + dob.format('dd-mm-yy') + '</td></tr>'));
```

However with this approach the sorting will not be correct on the DOB field. I would need a way to tell it to sort by dob.getTime().

Is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use the html5 data-* attributes. So sorting could be rectified thus:

```
table.row.add($('<tr><td data-sort=dob.getTime().toString()>' + name + '</td><td>' + dob.format('dd-mm-yy') + '</td></tr>'));
```

Note however there is an issue with using the data-* attributes on an uninitialised table. A solution to that issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706749/data-attributes-are-not-applied-when-i-add-a-row-dynamically/66711300#66711300)