# Data attributes are not applied when I add a row dynamically

Tags: datatables

When I add a row to a Datatable via javascript code then the search and sort options are not being applied. I modified the [data-attributes example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) thus:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
t.row.add($('<tr><td data-search="Tiger Nixon">T. Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>61</td><td data-order="1303689600">Mon 25th Apr 11</td><td data-order="320800">$320,800/y</td></tr>'));
t.draw();

} );
```

But if I then do a search for "Tiger" nothing comes up.

Is this expected behaviour and if so is there a way around it?

Full example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1osrLhx/)

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation, since a definitive answer needs more insight into DataTables internals: These HTML 5 `data-*` attributes are automatically detected by DataTables during initialization of a new table. If your table is empty, then that detection does not take place. If you have 1 initial row (with correctly cofigured `data-*` attributes), the detection does take place - and any subsequently added rows will also have their `data-*` attributes recognized by DataTables.

Comment: Workaround: put the `data-*` values in hidden columns, and then use column `render` functions, as shown in the [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#Computed-values) documentation.

Comment: Another option is to add a single row with "display: none" style and immediately delete it on start up. Have tested and it works. A bit hacky but its a solution at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that data-* attributes will only be detected if they are present in the initial table. So as a work around I came up with the following solution:

Define a dummy row in the initial table with any required data-* attributes:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style = "display: none;">
            <td data-search="">/td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

That row can then be deleted on startup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
t.row(0).remove();
t.row.add($('<tr><td data-search="Tiger Nixon">T. Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>61</td><td data-order="1303689600">Mon 25th Apr 11</td><td data-order="320800">$320,800/y</td></tr>'));
t.draw();
```

} );

Searching for "Tiger" now works