# Jquery datatable data-sort not working with dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable where I dynamically load data which has date using ajax request. So when I create a row I am doing something like:

```
<td data-sort="${parseInt(moment(item.OrderDate).unix())}"</td>
```

> The moment().unix() function is used to get the number of seconds
> since the Unix Epoch

So when my table loads I have something like this:

[image]

If you look at the sort arrows you can see that I am trying to sort the date in descending order. But it is not working. Nov 2020 is showing before May 8, and there are other dates mixed in random order. I know that the unix() function is working properly because if I inspect element for the first element i.e Nov 21 2020:
it has data sort value of:

data-sort="1605975621"

whereas May 8 2021 has a data-sort value of:

data-sort="1620481934"

So May should show up before November in a descending order but it does not. Can someone give me some directions please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you use to generate your datatable.  The [datatables tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) has some "starter" code, just add your HTML with `data-sort` etc and your configuration.

Comment: Impossible to say, without more details (for example, a [mre]). Having said that, you can check if [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706749/data-attributes-are-not-applied-when-i-add-a-row-dynamically) applies to your table.